# Creating a datafactory pipeline for updating an insering records

Tags: azure-data-factory, etl, insert-update, data-pipeline

I have one csv file which has data of 3 months and have a key column but it has empty values and I have a second file which has also three months records but one week after the records from the first file. They have overlapping records.

Now, I want to create a pipeline which find the new records of key columns in the second file and insert in the main database and also check the old records of the key columns where it is missi g and update it with the records from the new second file.

First file

study date  report no   pat no  examname

23/11/2023  WD2451  1345    MRI HIP
25/11/2023         1359 MRI Shoulder
29/11/2023      1754    MRI HIP

Second File

study date  report no   pat no  examname

23/11/2023  WD2451  1345    MRI HIP
01/12/2023  WD1983  1359    MRI Shoulder
04/12/2023      1754    MRI HIP

Answer (score 0):

Here are two files I have used:

**details1.csv:**

| study date | report no | pat no | examname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23/11/2023 | WD2451 | 1345 | MRI HIP |
| 25/11/2023 |  | 1359 | MRI Shoulder |
| 29/11/2023 |  | 1754 | MRI HIP |

**details2.csv:**

| study date | report no | pat no | examname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23/11/2023 | WD2451 | 1345 | MRI HIP |
| 1/12/2023 | WD1983 | 1359 | MRI Shoulder |
| 29/11/2023 | WD19834 | 1754 | MRI HIP |

Copy the first file from the source to the SQL database using the copy activity and insert option.

To find the new records of key columns in the second file and insert them in the main database table, and also check the old records of the key columns where they are missing and update them with the records from the new second file, you can use the **upsert** option in sink and select study date as the key column, as shown below:

[image]

After debugging the pipeline, you will get the updated table according to the second file, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I want to update the MRI shoulder record with the report no that is available in the second csv file instead of inserting it as a new record.

Comment: Then use examname as Key column.